# Porque el título no se vuelve más oscuro como los demás elementos?

Tags: css, css3

Tengo un header con un showcase con fondo una imagen y adentro del mismo un título h1 en color blanco. Porque cuando aplico un background con rgba para darle una transparencia el título no se ve afecto y solo la imagen de fondo?

HTML

```html
 <!-- Header: Showcase -->
    <header id="showcase">
        <div class="showcase-content">
            <h1 class="l-heading">
                The Sky Is The Limit
            </h1>
            <p class="lead">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda laborum veritatis molestias repudiandae dicta vitae.
            </p>
            <a href="#what" class="btn">Read More</a>
        </div>
    </header>
```

CSS

```css
    /* Showcase */
    #showcase {
      background: #333 url('../img/showcase.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
      height: 100vh;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    #showcase .showcase-content {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      text-align: center;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0 2rem;
      /* Overlay */
      position: absolute;
      top: 60px;
      left: 0;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La propiedad `background-color: rgba()` afecta solamente al color, no a los descendientes que el contenedor tenga, ya que el valor del **alfa** se aplica sobre el color en sí, siendo parte de su valor.

Si lo que que quieres es afectar a todos los descendientes del elemento puedes usar la propiedad `opacity`.

```css
.titulo1 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: red;
}

.titulo2 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="titulo1">
  <h2>Título 1</h2>
</div>

<div class="titulo2">
  <h2>Título 2</h2>
</div>
```